# Moving from Karate Style

Tags: karate

I have been practicing Karate-do Shotokan for 2 years now and I am moving to a town where there is no Shotokan Dojo.

I want to keep training Karate-do but there are only Gojo-ryu and Kyokushinkai dojos and I would like to know which one would be more like Shotokan or would fit better for me as far as I don't have much elasticity and my feet are a bit outward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kyokushin is a descendant of Shotokan, however there are significant differences in the forms.  Still it is more similar to Shotokan than is Goju Ryu.  According to this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyokushin), Goju Ryu also had some influence on Kyokushin.

FYI, Kyokushin is known for hard-sparring and emphasis on physical toughness. This may color your decision to join or not.

It does sound like you are open to different styles.  I suggest you try both and pick which one you like.  You will probably not be able to retain your Shotokan rank, so think of this as a time to branch out.  You might also consider non-Karate styles.

Comment: I practiced shotokan in my youth,  and achieved 1.kyu, before going off to boarding school. After a few years, I took up okinawa goju ryu,  which is very different,  not just in that it has completely different kata,  stances and techniques,  but also in that it is okinawan and not Japanese as shotokan is. Goju ryu is also much more concerned with traditional karate,  so it doesn't have as many factions as shotokan. I agree with @The Wudang Kid.  Try both and decide.